# auctex failing to render formula previews

Tags: latex, auctex, preview-latex

I am trying to get auctex on emacs to preview formulas but it doesnt seem to work and when I click preview, it produces the following error:

```
PDF2DSC sentinel: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
```

I have emacs, auctex and ghostscript installed on a windows 10 machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.